# SharePoint 2013 display custom user profile properties in person.aspx

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property

We want to add a couple of custom properties to the User profile to be shown on our mysite/person.aspx 
Currently, the layout of this page is the out of the box one, where the basic profile info is top right and the middle column is showing the about me info.

I've been looking around and I can't find how to add custom properties, I've found many tutorials on how to customize the master page but not the actual page.

My guess at this stage is I need to code a component that will show the custom properties and then use that in a web part... Is there any simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly follow the below steps,

1. Go to Central Administration
2. Click on Manage service applications -> Select User Profile Service
3. Click on Manage User Properties
4. Add a new Property and map it with AD field or edit an existing property.
5. Make sure you tick "Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page" and set "Default Privacy Setting" to "Everyone"

Comment: I had found that already, it's a bit limiting because the new properties will be underneath a "show more" toggle link, however there are ways to expand the section by default apparently so I'll try that, thanks